# Nginx restart says nothing in terminal

Tags: nginx

When I try to restart nginx it says nothing like:

```
>sudo service nginx restart
>sudo service nginx restart
```

When I enter `sudo nginx -t` it alsy says nothing!

When I try reload my host page - I see 404 nginx error.

In error log I see

```
09:09:18 [error] 489#0: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused)
while connecting to upstream, client: 54.93.93.219, 
server: psy-spb.pro, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1",
upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "psy-spb.pro"
```

with also

```
07:53 [crit] 491#0: unlink() "/var/run/udev/data/+pci:0000:00:00.0" failed 
(13: Permission denied)
2016/04/16 09:07:53 [crit] 491#0: cache file "/var/run/initramfs/overlayroot.log"
is too small
2016/04/16 09:07:53 [crit] 491#0: unlink() "/var/run/initramfs/overlayroot.log"
failed (13: Permission denied)
```

**The Question**

1. Why `nginx restart` says nothing?
2. How could I fix `connection refused` and `permission denied` errors? Where I should look for?

**My nginx.conf**
Sensitive strings:

```
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
#       fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
```

Another issue - I can't see any file in folder `/run/php/`, but `fastcgi_pass` is listening to `php7.0-fpm.sock` that is really does not exists in this folder.

### Update #1

My **nginx.conf** on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/DfBWzjtw), my site config is on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0pP55k8u).  **So I don't understand, why `sock` file is in my config but I see error that my host listens to `fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000`

Thank you

Comment: Which OS do you use? Nginx probabaly works correctly. `Another issue - I can't see any file in folder /run/php/, but fastcgi_pass is listening to php7.0-fpm.sock that is really does not exists in this folder.` That's the actual issue. Please see the relevant material of your OS on how to make php-fpm to work.

Comment: Best guess is the errors you see in the log need to be resolved before you can start nginx.

Comment: Thank you, guys. @Pothi, I'm use Ubuntu 14.04 on AWS EC2. Nginx was worked correctly before I started updating it and modifying `nginx.conf` file. So my issue is `php7.0-fpm.sock that is really does not exists in /run/php/` folder. Now I will try to find such an issues in relevant material to resolve this bug.

Comment: What about this recipe? The answer was to not use a .sock file at all. in `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` it has `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000` so in my nginx config I put `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;` instead of using something like `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;` as you can see in [Stack Overflow php-fpm doesn't create .sock file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35367676/php-fpm-doesnt-create-sock-file/35368500#35368500)

Comment: As you are using Ubuntu, check the path `/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock`

Comment: @nidhi Yes! I've found it in `/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock`.

Comment: But when I check my `error.log` - `2016/04/17 13:39:16 [error] 489#0: *199 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 52.59.246.106, server: psy-spb.pro, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "psy-spb.pro"`. My **nginx.conf** on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/DfBWzjtw), my site config is on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0pP55k8u).  **So I don't understand, why `sock` file is in my config but I see error that my host listens to `fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000`

Comment: It seems nginx is not using the current configuration. What do you see when you run `sudo service nginx configtest` ?

Comment: @nidhi - I think there is the main issue. I get an answer from `nginx` only when I put ` sudo nginx -t` with answer `nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
` but `nginx service` commands results in nothing at all! Even `sudo service nginx configtest` displays nothing.